# Android studio compilation issues (gradle task: compileDebugJavaWithJavac)

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I try to compile the project in Android Studio (2.3.3 and 3.0), but I keep to get the same error:
"Incompatible types: ImageView cannot be converted to int."
Android Studio doesn't indicate any compilation issues and the error doesn't contains the file name or the line number (double clicking on the error does nothing as well). The error appeared suddenly, I can't mention any unusual code changes that I made.

Please assume that I already restarted the Android Studio, cleaned the project and invalidated cache.

[image: An error in gradle build messages]

[image: An error in gradle console]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

I used not embedded JDK, so, apparently, what was compiled with Android Studio failed to compiled with different JDK.
So in order to solve issues like mine, just use embedded JDK location (you can set it in module setting, SDK location).

[image]